# Hibernate JPA Criteria API throwing NullPointerException and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using Hibernate 5.2.4.Final along with Spring boot 2.0 for my project and writing queries using JPA Criteria APIs.

For a long time, the hibernate was working fine, but from last few days, the `getSingleResult()`, `list()` methods are throwing either `NullPointerExceptions` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions`.

It is also happening when I try to get the child records, like OneToOne, ManyToOne, OneToMany using getters from the POJO class. Below is the POJO class.

Any help is appreciated.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {}, callSuper = true)
//@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(region = "common", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = {})
@Table(name = "node")
public class Node extends DateTimeConstants {

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "{NotEmpty.name}")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*$",
            message = "{Pattern.name}")
    @Length(min = 4, max = 50, message = "{Length.name}")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "kind")
    private String kind;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "template_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private NodeTemplate template;

    @Column(name = "current_status")
    private String currentStatus;

    @Column(name = "previous_status")
    private String previousStatus;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Type(type = "text")
    @Column(name = "reason")
    private String reason;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "spec_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Spec spec;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"projects", "node"})
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "node", targetEntity = NodeService.class)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
    private Set<NodeService> nodeService = new HashSet<NodeService>();
}`
```

The method responsible to get the row

```
@Override
public List<Node> getNodes(String type, Long id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    CriteriaBuilder criteria = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Node> query = criteria.createQuery(Node.class);

    Root<Node> from = query.from(Node.class);

    query.select(from)
            .where(criteria.equal(from.get("type"), type),
                    criteria.equal(from.get("spec").get("id"), id));

    return session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Below is the error stack which I am getting on my console.

```
 public NodeService getNodeService(String type, Long id) {

            List<Node> nodes = nodeDao.getNodes(type, id);

            if (nodes == null || nodes.size() == 0) {
                return null;
            }

return nodes.get(0).getNodeService();

            return anchorPeers;
        }
```

Error stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 148
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:215) ~[websocket-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at com.live.app.security.JwtAuthFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthFilter.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.vostics.blockchain.security.JwtAuthFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthFilter.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-security-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260) [jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281) [jetty-io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102) [jetty-io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118) [jetty-io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) [jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) [jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) [jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132) [jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762) ~[jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680) ~[jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 148
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaUtils.bitToLong(MysqlaUtils.java:68) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
```

---------- My Solution ---------------

It turns out BIT data type can create problems in reading and mapping the values with POJO variables.

Comment: This is me asking for full stack traces.

Comment: you have past the part which is not important in the stacktrace. update the question with stacktrace for caused by exception (Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 148).

Answer (score 0):

One problem with the `getSingleResult()` methot could be, that it throws exeptions if the query gives back nothing (no rows found within your select). Then it throws a `NoResultException` at runtime.

if you try to do something with the Result you will get an `Nullpointer` exception if im correct, since there is no Object to do something with.

Try to use the `getResultList()` method witch gives you all the rows the query returns in a list.

Make the Query so there comes only the specific row back you wish for or at leas as the First Object in the List. Then you can get the Object like this:

```
List results = query.getResultList();
Entity foundEntity = null;
if(!results.isEmpty()){
    // ignores multiple results
    foundEntity = results.get(0);
}
```

Comment: The data is available in the DB and if I try to run the query which Hibernate prints in the logs on the console, I can see that the rows are matched.

Comment: Can it be the case, that I have to instantiate the Set variable in the POJO like @JsonIgnoreProperties({"projects", "node"})
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "node", targetEntity = NodeService.class)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
    private Set<NodeService> nodeService = new HashSet<NodeService>();

Comment: Could you post the Code from witch you execute the HQL and what you do after the Execution with the Object (if the RuntimeException is not already thrown)? Also could you add the Stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I have added the method where the data is being fetched and the method where it is being used. I have also added the error stack trace.

Comment: I think the problem could be with the "spec". As far as i know you are looking to get the field "spec" in the Node POJO. But i think the way your query in the method works is that its looking for the "spec" field in the DB witch does not exist. Try replacing "spec" with the actual Column name as it is in the POJO "spec_id" in your method.

Comment: I think I found a solution, it was happening because of the boolean type variable in one of the POJO. It turns out, one should avoid using BIT data type columns in MySQL. https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution. Sorry that i could not help you with the problem. But add an answer for yourself, so that others can see that and dont have to search again for the solution